# Calculator Functioning

Tags: eclipse, sum, calculator

I am trying to obtain calculator functioning of simple on button sum. In this one text field will display digits one after another seperated by + sign and one calculate button will display result. I am stuck in finding the sum in `ans()` function. Please help or suggest.

My `Sum` button calls function `sumclicked` and `Equals` button calls `result`

```
public void result(View v) { // This will only display the resut

    TextView answer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.output);
    answer.setText(String.valueOf(ans()));

}


public int ans()
{ // This is just for calculating the sum value to display
    int ans=0;

    int num2=0;

    int sum=sumclicked()+num2;
    num2=sum=ans;


    return ans;

     }


public void sumclicked (View v)
{ // This is display of textfield. Eg 55 + 12 + 99 

    EditText value=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);
    String ans=value.getText().toString();


    String ans1= ans +"+";

    TextView tempview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.input);
    tempview.setText(ans1);

}

public int sumclicked()
{ // This parses each string digit to int and returns it for getting the summation done.

    EditText value=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);
    String ans=value.getText().toString();
    Integer ans1=Integer.parseInt(ans);
    return ans1;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on: "stuck in finding the sum"?  Are you getting an error? We need more context.  Also, is this Android programming?

Comment: Yes it is android programming. I am not being able to solve the ans() function, whose value I want to call in the result(View) function. If Clearly what I have written in the ans() cannot work as the num2 will be considered zero everytime the summation is tried to find out. Am I clear here?